# I can't find the process id

Tags: pm2

I have PM2 on a GoDaddy Ubuntu cloud server. `pm2 list` shows as follows:

[image]

Is the fourth column the process id?  Every one seems to be 0. Is there something wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 4th column is the number of restarts. It's supposed to show a little icon, like this:

[image: pm2 list view with a narrow terminal]

The reason its not showing the process id column is because your terminal window is too narrow. Try extending it and running `pm2 list` again. I believe this responsive list view is a recently added feature.

Once your terminal is wide enough, it should look like this:

[image: pm2 list view with a wide terminal]

as you can see the process id (pid) is now shown.

Comment: Or in the case of ssh, widen your ssh window.

Comment: it's odd that it expands `Name` to `App name` but `memory` gets shortened to `mem` in the wide version.

Answer (score 0):

check your error log maybe can get something useful tips, and check have you turn on "watch" options? if you turn on the "watch" options, pm2 will be restart when the file had changed, so you need to add the log files in "ignore_watch" options, or pm2 will be always restart loop because the log file always has changed